# What does the Jenkins iLmBjh process do?

Tags: jenkins

Today I noticed that several of our Jenkins jobs (which are independant, different projects and everything) failed.
I investigated an finally listed all processes on the machine that Jenkins uses with the `top` command. It showed me a very greedy process launched by Jenkins, which name is **iLmBjh**. Not very clear, isn't it?
I tried some things and finally killed it. But it appeared again when I launched a new Jenkins job.
Do someone know what this process does? It's the first time I see it on the processes list...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I found the problem and it's kind of surprising. On our Jenkins instance, we had the JiraTestReporter plugin installed. Our Jira licence ended today. And when I checked the Jenkins logs, it was full of Jira error messages.
What is disturbing is that we weren't using it at all... in any of our jobs!
I uninstalled it and was able to run my job again. The iLmBjh process did not come back.